# Hostgator Vps 1 install yum packages

Tags: php, rpm, yum

I am trying to install packages using repositories.

I have tried Webtatic and install using

rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm

I then try

yum install --enablerepo=webtatic package-name

yum install cpanel-php53.x86_64

but I always get setting up install process nothing to do

How would I get php to work on this server? And also yum list install returns along list of packages do I have to do anything extra with these packages to use them

Comment: Are you running as root?

Comment: i abandoned host gator, and I was running as root

Answer (score -1):

For custom rpm build, follow this guide.

```
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/CustomBuildRpm
```